# Rails association access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wish I described this better, but it's the best I know how. I have two classes Cars and Colors. Each can have many of each other through a association class CarColors. The association is set up correctly I'm positive of this but I can't seem to get this to work:

```
@carlist = Cars.includes(:Colors).all

@carlist.colors
```

**ERROR**

```
@carlist[0].colors
```

**WORKS**

My question is how can I iterate over the @carlist without declaring a index as in the successful example? Below is a few things I have tried which also fail:

```
@carlist.each do |c|
c.colors
end

@carlist.each_with_index do |c,i|
c[i].colors
end
```

Comment: I believe you have to do something with the colour, try printing it in your each block
 @carlist.each do |c|
   p c.colors
 end

Comment: When you are doing `@carlist.each_with_index do |c,i| c[i].colors end` it should be `@carlist.each_with_index do |c,i| @carlist[i].colors` end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example fails because `Car.includes(:colors).all` returns an array of cars, not a single car, so the following will fail, because `#colors` is not defined for the array

```
@cars = Car.includes(:colors).all
@cars.colors #=> NoMethodError, color is not defined for Array
```

The following will work, because the iterator will have an instance of car

```
@cars.each do |car|
  puts car.colors # => Will print an array of color objects
end
```

`each_with_index` will work as well, but it is a bit different, as the first object
is the same as the each loop car object, the second object is the index

```
@cars.each_with_index do |car, index|
  puts car.colors # => Will print an array of color objects
  puts @cars[index].colors # => Will print an array of color objects
  puts car == @cars[index] # => will print true
end
```

Comment: its `@cars[index].colors` and `car == @cars[index]`

Comment: @ShreyasAgarwal: Thanks, missed those!

Comment: Also it's pritty ugly idea to use `#all` only for iterate over all items.

Comment: @Hauleth: Are you thinking of using `.find_each`? If there are less than 1000 items, .`.all` and `.find_each` will operate the same. Also, I use `.all` in this example, as `.all` is used in the question

Comment: Thanks, this worked. my end result was using @carlist.each_with_index do |c,i| {@carcolorlist[i] = c.color.push} end